# REST Call issue for IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot

Here is the function i have which is trying to make a simple REST call.

```
private String getWorkdayDataArray() throws IllegalArgumentException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException, IOException {
        String url = getWorkers();
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        return EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
    }

private String getWorkers() throws IllegalArgumentException, KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException
    {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
        HttpEntity<String> entity = getEntityForWorkday();
        String resp = null;
        String url = String.format("https://XXXXXXXXXXX.com/dorqers/v5?key=%s",AUTH_KEY);
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> respEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET,entity,String.class);
            resp = respEntity.getBody();
            resp.replaceAll(" ", "");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
return resp;
    }

public HttpEntity<String> getEntityForWorkday()
    {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Authorization",AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN);
        headers.set("Content-Type","application/json");
        return new HttpEntity<>("parameters",headers);
    }

    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException
    {
        //Disable SSL
        org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
        SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
                .build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
                .build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
                new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

The get call is working just fine in postman. When i try to do this from my api, i get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: {"total_workers":2228,"workers":
[{"worker":{"update_identifier":"asssy25-JUN-18 06.24.52.429287 AM -05:00","identity":
{"first_name":"damam",
"middle_name":"A",
"last_name":"Craft",
"preferred_first_name":"damam",
"preferred_last_name":"Craft",
"lan_id":"T003","worker_type":"Team Member",
"active_directory_worker_id":"01039932","is_manager":"N"
},"location":{
"location_type":"OFFICE","work_state":"CA"
},"email":
{"work_email":"damam.craft@tt.com",
"supervisor_work_email":"barra.kosi@tt.com"
},"job":
{"job_description":"Sr Coordinator Service Center - US",
"job_entry_date":"2011-04-10",
"pay_type_code":"Hourly",
"position_entry_date":"2011-04-10",
"active_directory_supervisor_id":"hhhgffssaa",
"standard_hours":"40.00","weekly_work_hours":"40.00",
"time_type":"Full time"
},"employee":
{"employee_status_description":"Active"},
"employee_action":{"hire_date":"1978-04-04","rehire_date":"1978-04-04"}}},
```

It goes and prints the entire JSON object that is returning form the GET call. Here is the remaining part of the error log:

```
 at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
        at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:66)
        at application.Collector.WorkdayCollector.getWorkdayDataArray(WorkdayCollector.java:65)
        at application.Collector.WorkdayCollector.getWorkdayData(WorkdayCollector.java:43)
        at application.Application.lambda$run$0(Application.java:26)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at application.Application.main(Application.java:13)
    Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: <Prints entire JSON Again>

at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChar(URI.java:3031)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3047)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850)
    ... 11 more
```

I have done some research and the error is most likely to happen when there are blank spaces in the URL. I have double checked and there seems to be no spaces in my URL. The strangest thing is the log is printing the entire JSON but i have not printed it in my code explicitly any where.

Any help on this matter is highly appreciated.

Comment: From the stacktrace is seems as if you succeed in getting the workers, but then in `getWorkdayDataArray` you use the result from `getWorkers` as a URL. This of course fails as the `getWorkers` returns JSON. Did you mean to use a different URL or just parse the JSON?

Comment: You are right. I dont know why i have the getWorkdayDataArray in there. I  have deleted that and using the getWorkdayDataArray method to parse the JSON. Thanks a lot